# Are toxiclibs libraries compatible with processing.js?

Tags: processing

I have a Processing sketch that will be running in a gallery setting soon.  I'm considering porting the sketch to processing.js, but I am unsure if you can use the toxiclibs libraries in processing.js.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If it's going to run a gallery soon and everything works fine, don't change anything yet just to have everything working as expected:"If ain't broke, don't fix it"

When porting code over to processing.js some functions might be slower or not implemented so best not to take a chance at this point. In the future however if you plan to use processing.js and toxiclibs, you can use the [toxiclibs.js port](http://haptic-data.com/toxiclibsjs/)

[image: toxilibs.js preview 1]
[image: toxiclibs.js preview 2]
[image: toxiclibs.js preview 3]